# React WebStorm DevTools like in Codesandbox?

Tags: reactjs, ide, webstorm, codesandbox

I've got pretty great time with React DevTools [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io) with all React app structure and I can see there all the props and states.

Is there any way to get these tools in WebStorm?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no such feature in the IDE, please follow [WEB-36512](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36512) for updates